# Why read_xml() is not reading the file as expected?

Tags: r, rvest, xml2

How can I avoid the error of tag mismatch while reading html file? The following code replicates the error I'm receiving related to `read_xml()`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(xml2)
library(rvest)
library(tibble)


temp <- tempfile()

"http://www1.caixa.gov.br/loterias/_arquivos/loterias/D_megase.zip" %>%
    download.file(temp)

megasena <- unz(temp, "D_MEGA.HTM") %>%
    read_xml() %>%
    html_table() %>%
    .[[1]]
```

The error returned is:

```
  Error in doc_parse_raw(x, encoding = encoding, base_url = base_url, as_html = as_html,  : 
      Opening and ending tag mismatch: img line 1 and p [76]
```

Comment: Perhaps the file contains malformed xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is indeed an HTML/.HTM file, why not read it using `read_html()`?

This works:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(tidyr)
library(xml2)
library(rvest)
library(tibble)


temp <- tempfile()

"http://www1.caixa.gov.br/loterias/_arquivos/loterias/D_megase.zip" %>%
  download.file(temp)

megasena <- unz(temp, "D_MEGA.HTM") %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_table() %>%
  .[[1]]

head(megasena)
#>   Concurso Data Sorteio    1\xaa Dezena 2ª Dezena 3ª Dezena 4ª Dezena
#> 1        1   11/03/1996           41         5         4        52
#> 2        2   18/03/1996            9        39        37        49
#> 3        3   25/03/1996           36        30        10        11
#> 4        3   25/03/1996           36        30        10        11
#> 5        4   01/04/1996            6        59        42        27
#> 6        5   08/04/1996            1        19        46         6
#>   5ª Dezena 6ª Dezena Arrecadacao_Total Ganhadores_Sena Cidade    UF
#> 1        30        33              0,00               0  &nbsp &nbsp
#> 2        43        41              0,00               1           PR
#> 3        29        47              0,00               2           RN
#> 4        29        47              0,00               2           SP
#> 5         1         5              0,00               0  &nbsp &nbsp
#> 6        16         2              0,00               0  &nbsp &nbsp
#>    Rateio_Sena Ganhadores_Quina Rateio_Quina Ganhadores_Quadra
#> 1         0,00               17    39.158,92              2016
#> 2 2.307.162,23               65    14.424,02              4488
#> 3   391.192,51               62    10.515,93              4261
#> 4   391.192,51               62    10.515,93              4261
#> 5         0,00               39    15.322,24              3311
#> 6         0,00               98     5.318,10              5399
#>   Rateio_Quadra Acumulado Valor_Acumulado Estimativa_Prêmio
#> 1        330,21       SIM    1.714.650,23              0,00
#> 2        208,91       NÃO            0,00              0,00
#> 3        153,01       NÃO            0,00              0,00
#> 4        153,01       NÃO            0,00              0,00
#> 5        180,48       SIM      717.080,75              0,00
#> 6         96,53       SIM    1.342.488,85              0,00
#>   Acumulado_Mega_da_Virada
#> 1                     0,00
#> 2                     0,00
#> 3                     0,00
#> 4                     0,00
#> 5                     0,00
#> 6                     0,00
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>